# How do you debug UI component for react-native?

Tags: react-native

How do you develop and debug UI component for react-native? such as style, background color,size etc.
as https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/229 show that we can not use chrome develop tools to debug UI component(but we can use this tools to debug JS code).

Comment: Have you tried pressing command + d in the simulator, and bringing up the menu, then clicking "Show Inspector"? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: yes, I tried. I want to develop on UI Component.